# Return an array By reference

Tags: c

I have the following method:

```
BIGNUM[] allocateBigNumArray(int size){
    BIGNUM array[size];
    return array;
}
```

That is called from this one:

```
  int MPIReceiveBigNum(BIGNUM **numbers, int size) {
     numbers=allocateBigNumArray(size);
  }
```

What I try to achieve is to allocate an N-sized array of BIGNUM and return it by reference in a similar manner such as OPENSSL, MPI does.

So my question is Should in `MPIReceiveBigNum` the numbers be of type `BIGNUM**`?

Comment: This is not C..

Comment: You cannot return the address of a local (auto) variable from within a function, since the variable no longer exists after the function returns.

Comment: @DavidRTribble: You very well "*could*", but you shouldn't for the reasons mentioned. ;)

Comment: Assuming `allocateBigNumArray()` would savely allocate (what it does not), then it should be `*numbers = allocateBigNumArray(...`.